# Every php page doesn't load in my website

Tags: php, html, hosting, web-hosting

Long story short that might not be related but it will give you an idea. I am trying to load PHPMailer without composer into my website. On localhost it works it sends emails and the PHP version (localhost) is 7.2.11. Now it gave me an Internal 500 error which I assumed it might be from not finding the PHPMailer folder. The server PHP version is 5.6.

Now the actual problem, I have tried to load a simple echo of hello world. The index.html is working, I mean displaying and I have did a redirect to the file with the echo hello world (hello.php). It still gives me an internal 500 error when redirecting to the php page.

Comment: did you build the remote webserver?

Comment: no, a friend's of mine did it

Comment: perhaps he/she would be a good candidate to answer this - is PHP even installed?

Comment: I mean he says yes. He told me he has PHP 5.6 installed. I am waiting for him to create a new ftp location to see what is the problem.

Comment: PHP 5.6 is beyond end of life and does not get security updates. **Do not use it**. Use a supported version of PHP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I said to come back here and to say how I solved my PHPMailer issue. Comment this line with //$mail->IsSMTP();